# Старт парсинга после запуска приложения

Tags: android, jsoup, синтаксический-анализ

Как запустить парсинг сразу после запуска программы?
Через `webview` получалось, сейчас возникла проблема с `jsoup`, запускается только через кнопку.
пример кода:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new MyParser().execute("http://site.ru/");
    }

    public class MyParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... links) {  
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(links[0]).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return doc.title();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а куда ты выводишь результат? textView = null

Comment: не понял?
типа TextView tvInfo?

Comment: textView = (TextView) findById(R.id.textView1); 

или какая ошибка?

Comment: ошибки вообще нет, просто парсинг не запускается, черный экран

Comment: это полный код? так как он сейчас - он не рабочий

Comment: да, вот добавил:

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findById(R.id.textView1); 
    

  new MyParser().execute("http://site.ru/");
   }

   private TextView findById(int textView1)
   {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return null;
   }
стало вылетать через несколько сек.

Comment: логи покажи, я же код писал для примера

Comment: AndroidRuntime(3147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 00:47:56.549 E/AndroidRuntime(3147): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 00:47:56.549 E/AndroidRuntime(3147):  at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity$MyParser.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:51)
04-30 00:47:56.549 E/AndroidRuntime(3147):  at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity$MyParser.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java)
04-30 00:47:56.549 E/AndroidRuntime(3147):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
04-30 00:47:56.549 E/AndroidRuntime(3147):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)

весь лог не влез

Comment: так у тебя findById переопределен и возвращает null.
убери этот метод и работай тем, что есть в activity

Answer (score 2):

Добавь следующее в onCreate

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id."твой id в разметке");
textView.setText(String.valueOf(result)); - если он не стринговый!
В твоем случае просто:
textView.setText(result);
```